# JQuery datePicker SelectMultiple format dd/mm/yy

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Got the datePicker working to select multiple dates. When the user selects multiple dates and closes the calendar the textbox displays the dates in the format:

```
Thur Jan 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000
Fri Jan 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000
Sat Jan 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000,
```

My Code:

```
<script>

            $("#HolidayDate").addClass('date-pick');
            $('.date-pick').datePicker//({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).val();
            (
                    {
                        createButton: false,
                        displayClose: true,
                        closeOnSelect: false,
                        selectMultiple: true,                  
                    }
            )
            .bind(
                'click',
                function () {
                    $(this).dpDisplay();
                    this.blur();
                    return false;
                }
            )
            .bind(
                'dateSelected',
                function (e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
                    console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
                        + 'selected ' + selectedDate);
                }
            )
            .bind(
                'dpClosed',
                function (e, selectedDates) {
                    console.log('You closed the date picker and the ' // wrap
                        + 'currently selected dates are:');
                    console.log(selectedDates);
                    $('#HolidayDate').val( selectedDates );
                }
            );

    </script>
```

---

However I would like the date to display as dd-mm-yy.
If I use the commented out line

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker//({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).val();

and run it as    $('.date-pick').datePicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).val();
```

The textbox will return the date in the correct format but now it only allows me to select one date at a time.

Please advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you left ouy the options saying it is a selectmultiple.

try

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker
            (
                    {
                        createButton: false,
                        displayClose: true,
                        closeOnSelect: false,
                        selectMultiple: true,   
                        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'               
                    }
            )
```

See that i added it to the previous options you had?

**Edit**

After reading kelvinlucks documentation on this, I see what's causing your problem. The date you get in return is a javascript Date object and not a string. You are free to format it as you wish, but in your overloaded methods dateSelected and dpClosed they are just printed without formatting.

Try this:

```
.bind(
    'dateSelected',
    function(e, selectedDate, $td, state)
    {
        var date = selectedDate.getDate() + "-" + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +     selectedDate.getFullYear();
        console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
            + 'selected ' + date);

    }
)
```

My formatting of dates isn't so good, but you get the point. Here's a post on formatting dates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply jonas....Sorry but I should have mentioned that I previously tried that also but no joy...cant understand why though....Any suggestions?  Thaks

Comment: What version of datepicker (jquery ui) are you using? I can see no optino "selectMultiple" in the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: It doesn't seem that jquery ui supports selecting multiple dates. But why reinvent the wheel, a lot of people have already made a solution for this. For instance take a look at http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a plug in for the datepicker I found on http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html, it allows me to select multiple dates and return the list to the text box, however I am trying to change the format of the dates returned from Thur Jan 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000
Fri Jan 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000
Sat Jan 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT +0000, to dd/mm/yy, dd/mm/yy, dd/mm/yy

Comment: Did you see that I updated my comment? Did you understand it?

Comment: Yes jonas I understood the comment, everything is now working, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

try to select dateformat using .bind(Date.format = 'dd-mm-yyyy')
and use selectMultiple: true

Comment: Thanks for the reply abhi...do you mean like this... .bind(Date.format = 'dd-mm-yyyy')
       'click',
       function () {
           $(this).dpDisplay();
           this.blur();         
           return false;
       }
      )....still no joy, any suggestios?